How to fix "Keep Stacked by type..." setting for desktop icon arrangement on Ubuntu
I've been trying to use the "Keep stacked by type..." feature in Desktop Icon Settings on Ubuntu 24.10. However, whenever I enable this feature, the desktop icons disappear. To make them visible again, I have to disable this feature and use other icon arrangement options. I've encountered this issue in previous versions of Ubuntu as well, and it hasn't been resolved. If anyone has a solution for this, please let me know. Please refer to the video for more understanding.
Thanks
